# angular select model not work with initial value

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple 'select' element binding to value using angular model, like this:

```
<select ng-model="data.value">
  <option ng-repeat="d in list" value="{{d.id}}">{{d.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The binding is working well (I add 2 selects elements bind to the same var, and when i change one of them the second one change correctly).
My problem is that the select element is not set correctly in the loading to the initial value of the variable.

My controller code is:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{id:1,name:'aaa'},
              {id:2,name:'bbb'},
              {id:3,name:'ccc'},
              {id:4,name:'ddd'},
              {id:5,name:'eee'}];

    $scope.data = {value:2};
});
```

An example set at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/sr526Qfvcju5W0xU4MDF).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use $scope.data = {value:'2'};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your model with

```
$scope.data = {value:'2'}
```

You can check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngoptions)  in more detail

Answer (score 0):

I have Got a Solution For You :-

You can use ng-init to initialize the first one. ng-model can take care from there check the below Plunker for Working Out put

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <!--   first select:
  <select ng-model="data.value">
    <option ng-repeat="d in list" value="{{d.id}}">{{d.name}}</option>
  </select> -->

    <br/>

    First Select :- 

    <select ng-init="data.value = list[0]" 
        ng-model="data.value" 
        ng-options="d.name for d in list">
  </select>

  <br/>
    second select:
     <select ng-init="data.value = list[0]" 
        ng-model="data.value" 
        ng-options="d.name for d in list">
  </select>
    <!--<select ng-model="data.value">-->
    <!--  <option ng-repeat="d in list" value="{{d.id}}">{{d.name}}</option>-->
    <!--</select>-->

  <br/>
  selected value: {{data.value}}
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IydWDWosdLo6aSumb1ic?p=preview

Note :- I Just Updated it in 
Plunker  or Just Replace your code with the above !!

Answer (score 0):

I got your plunker working with ng-options:

```
first select:
<select ng-model="data.value" ng-options="d.id as d.name for d in list">
</select>

<br/>

second select:
<select ng-model="data.value" ng-options="d.id as d.name for d in list">
</select>
```